# Merging two data table(Same schema) in VB and get only unmatched rows

Tags: vb.net

I have two data tables. I want to merge them and want to get only unmatched rows from both data tables. Can anyone please help on this?

Currently I am using the following code, but it's returning nothing:

```
Actual_Table = myDataSet_Actual.Tables("Actuals")
Planned_Table = myDataset_Planned.Tables("Planned")

Planned_Table.AcceptChanges()
Planned_Table.Merge(Actual_Table, False)

change = Planned_Table.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)
DGV1.DataSource = change ' DGV1= Data grid view
```

Comment: What are you using? VB.NET or VB6?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am using VB 2010 , Will you please help me on this ?

Comment: And how do you compare two rows from different tables? They have the same structure?

Comment: basically i am trying to merge two tables(These two tables have same schema) and then i am checking which rows has been changed after merge. These above tables going to contain lots of common rows and that is why i want to check for unmatched rows from both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You can do this with the following code, but please read on for more details:

```vb
change = Planned_Table.AsEnumerable _
                      .Except(Actual_Table.AsEnumerable, DataRowComparer.Default) _ 
                      .CopyToDataTable
```

### There are a couple things to note here:

As pointed out in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460953/datatable-merge-and-datatable-importrow-does-not-change-rowstate), `DataTable.Merge` does not change row state, so looking for rows with `DataRowState.Added` will always come up empty.

Also, `Merge` adds every row from the second table to the first, so *everything* from the second table would have come up even if the RowState *had* changed.

Finally, supposing we only added unique values from the second datatable to the first, we'd only get back the elements that were in the second set, but not in the first.  Perhaps that is what you wanted, but I'll delineate both options in case you really want either one.

### The Tools We'll Need

As found in other SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840539/how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-two-lists-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815387/compare-two-lists-c-sharp-linq?rq=1), we can find the right set of entries by using any of the [`LINQ Set Operations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx):

- [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)
- [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx)
- [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)
- [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

You can explore each of these further in MSDN, but just as an FYI, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961910/joining-or-appending-two-ienumerable-sequences/4961949#4961949) SO Question, `Union` and `Concat` will both append an enumerable onto another, but Union will remove duplicates (when checking the equality of `DataRow`s, you must pass in the overloaded `IEqualityComparer` = `DataRowComparer.Default`)

Also, we'll want to Enumerate over a DataTable, so to do this we'll need to call the [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) method from the `DataTableExtensions` namespace.

### Solution Setup

Just so we're looking at the same code, here are some basic DataTables on which we can perform set operations

```vb
Dim dt, dataTable1, dataTable2 As New DataTable

With dt.Columns
    .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    .Add("Name", GetType(String))
End With

dataTable1 = dt.Clone
dataTable2 = dt.Clone

With dataTable1.Rows
    .Add(1, "Tod")
    .Add(2, "Jim")
End With

With dataTable2.Rows
    .Add(2, "Jim")
    .Add(3, "Han")
End With
```

### Solution Sets

So if you want just the new items in the second table that don't appear in the first table, then you want a `Right Outer Join`:

[image: Right Outer Join]

If you want all the data that is different between the two sets, you want a `Full Outer Join` that excludes an `Inner Join`

[image: Right Outer Join]

You can read more about different sets and the joins that create them in this Jeff Atwood [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

### Code

If you want the first option, you can get the elements in and only in the the second set by calling `Except` on the second `Datatable` and passing in the first

```
Dim just2 As DataTable
just2 = dataTable2.AsEnumerable _
                  .Except(dataTable1.AsEnumerable, DataRowComparer.Default) _
                  .CopyToDataTable()
```

The output will be:

```
| ID | Name |
| 3  | Han  |
```

If you want the unique values in each set, you'll have to call distinct twice and then join those two values.  We won't need to pass in the `DataRowComparer` to the `Union` method because we've guaranteed that there are no duplicates in the two tables

```
Dim just1 As IEnumerable(Of DataRow)
Dim just2 As IEnumerable(Of DataRow)
Dim union As DataTable

'get rows that are only in table1
just1 = dataTable1.AsEnumerable.Except(dataTable2.AsEnumerable, DataRowComparer.Default)

'get rows that are only in table2
just2 = dataTable2.AsEnumerable.Except(dataTable1.AsEnumerable, DataRowComparer.Default)

'get all unique rows
union = just1.Union(just2).CopyToDataTable
```

Since we won't need the unique element sets individually, there's no need to call `CopyToDataTable` just so we can cast back into an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` with `AsEnumerable`

The output of union will be:

```
| ID | Name |
| 1  | Tod  |
| 3  | Han  |
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-compare-rows

In the example it writes the compare result in the console, but I guess you can do the magic ;)

Good luck!

**EDIT:** actually, if your `DataTable`s have the same number of rows and you are comparing the rows one to one, you should change the `For Each` statements for one `For` statement. Something like:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RowNo - 1
    'compare datatable1_row(i) with datatable2_row(i) and do the magic
Next
```

Comment: This is a dangerously outdated link.  Please don't implement your own DataRow comparison method when .NET has the built in [`DataRowComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer.aspx) Class